# PyQt: translate module strings at runtime

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, translation

Strings in `QObject`s are translated at runtime. If the translator is changed, all those strings are refreshed. However, strings declared at module level or even static class attributes, are translated at import time.

I can see 3 ways of allowing module strings to be translated, none of which seems totally satisfying to me :

- Import the module after the translator is installed (see [here](https://plashless.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/internationalizing-python-pyqt-apps/) (paragraph *Install translator early*)). This may not be handy but is feasible, as long as one doesn't need to change language at runtime.
- Make the strings class instance attributes. Well... yes, obviously. But this breaks the design.
- Keep the strings at module level. Use `QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate()` to let them be picked up by pylupdate. Then translate them (again) at runtime by calling `self.tr()` or `QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate()` on them. Example :

  ```
  translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
  strings = [translate('foo'), translate('bar')]

  class my_class(QObject):

      def __init__(self):
          for s in strings:
              print(self.tr(s))
  ```

  When doing this, one must ensure that no translator will be installed before module import, otherwise, the module strings are translated at import time (translate() in declaration) and retranslated at run time (self.tr() in class instance). In the general case this won't be seen: self.tr() will try to translate an already translated string which is not likely to exist in the original language string set, and it will silently return the string itself.

  But if for instance an English string happens to translates into a French string that is equal to another English string appearing in the same class, then the French translation of this string will be displayed instead.

Is there a clean way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [QT_TR_NOOP](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#QT_TR_NOOP) (or [QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP) if you need to provide context).

This will mark a string literal as needing translation (i.e. so that it is picked up by `pylupdate`), but it does not do any translation at runtime (nor import time).

Thus:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QT_TR_NOOP

some_string = QT_TR_NOOP('Hello World')

class SomeClass(QObject):
    def do_something(self):
        print(self.tr(some_string))
```

The `tr()` here will translate `some_string` dynamically at runtime, but it will itself be ignored by `pylupdate` because it does not contain a string literal.

Note that `QT_TR_NOOP` could be aliased to the name `tr` in python (or you could just define your own dummy `tr` function), because `pyludate` only ever does static analysis:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QT_TR_NOOP as tr

some_string = tr('Hello World')
```

You can also use a true alias (i.e. something other than `tr`, `translate`, `__tr`, etc), by using the corresponding `pylupdate` option:

```
pylupdate -tr-function FOO file.pro
```

Comment: Thanks (again), ekhumoro. I can't test right now, but you're right. This is the way. I've been struggling for a while with this and was in a dead end. Glad I asked.

Comment: When I use `QT_TR_NOOP`, the string appears in the `.ts` file in the context `@default` and I don't know how to use it at runtime. So I use `ST_TRANSLATE_NOOP`, specify a context (any string), then at I call `runtime QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate`, specifying the same string as context.